# Order by custom post type navigation by ACF date picker

Tags: wordpress, arguments, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I am trying to do post navigation for a custom post type called 'prime-ministers', order by an Advanced custom fields date picker.

On the actual archive page it works fine (which uses FacetWP), but for the post type navigation, it jumps all over the place, and I can't work out why. The archive page is grouped by century, then by date, but I didn't think this would have any effect on the single posts navigation.

There doesn't seem to be any logic behind the way it orders them. It's not alphabetical or in other way that I can see.

The first code is the same query use in FacetWP, but I think it uses slightly different syntax

```
<div class="prime-ministers-post-nav full-width blue-bg">
 <?php
 
 /* Infinite next and previous post looping */
 if( get_adjacent_post(false, '', true) ) { 
     previous_post_link('%link', '&larr; Previous Post');
 } else { 
     $arg_prev = array(
         "post_type" => "prime-ministers",
         "post_status" => "publish",
           "meta_query" => [
             "sort_0" => [
               "key" => "pm_century",
               "type" => "CHAR"
             ],
             "sort_1" => [
               "key" => "serving_period_1_start",
               "type" => "CHAR"
             ]
           ],
           "orderby" => [
             "sort_0" => "DESC",
             "sort_1" => "DESC"
           ],
           "posts_per_page" => -1
      );
     $first = new WP_Query($arg_prev); 
     $first->the_post();
     echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="prev-link"> &larr; Previous Post</a>';
     wp_reset_query();
 }; 
 
 if( get_adjacent_post(false, '', false) ) { 
     next_post_link('%link', 'Next Post &rarr;');
 } else { 
     $arg_next = array(
        "post_type" => "prime-ministers",
             "post_status" => "publish",
               "meta_query" => [
                 "sort_0" => [
                   "key" => "pm_century",
                   "type" => "CHAR"
                 ],
                 "sort_1" => [
                   "key" => "serving_period_1_start",
                   "type" => "CHAR"
                 ]
               ],
               "orderby" => [
                 "sort_0" => "ASC",
                 "sort_1" => "ASC"
               ],
               "posts_per_page" => -1
          );
     $last = new WP_Query($arg_next); 
     $last->the_post();
     echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="next-link">Next Post &rarr;</a>';
     wp_reset_query();
 }; 
 
 ?>
</div>
```

Technically, I don't need the century, only the serving period one start date so I tried this, but same issue

```
<div class="prime-ministers-post-nav full-width blue-bg">
 <?php
 
 /* Infinite next and previous post looping */
 if( get_adjacent_post(false, '', true) ) { 
     previous_post_link('%link', '&larr; Previous Post');
 } else { 
     $arg_prev = array(
          'post_type' => 'prime-ministers',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'meta_key' => 'serving_period_1_start',
          'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
          'order'             => 'DESC',
          'posts_per_page' => -1
      );
     $first = new WP_Query($arg_prev); 
     $first->the_post();
     echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="prev-link"> &larr; Previous Post</a>';
     wp_reset_query();
 }; 
 
 if( get_adjacent_post(false, '', false) ) { 
     next_post_link('%link', 'Next Post &rarr;');
 } else { 
     $arg_next = array(
        'post_type' => 'prime-ministers',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key' => 'serving_period_1_start',
        'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'    => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
     );
     $last = new WP_Query($arg_next); 
     $last->the_post();
     echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="next-link">Next Post &rarr;</a>';
     wp_reset_query();
 }; 
 
 ?>
</div>
```

I have also tried ordering by

```
meta_value_num
```

and

```
meta_value
```

for both

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139453/filter-next-post-link-and-previous-post-link-by-meta-key